# fieldset inline style is not working(IE)

Tags: html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a fieldset like below and a below generic css for all fieldsets. I am using ie browser.
when i am giving style="margin-bottom: 2px" inline of the fieldset, it is not overriding fieldset#counts div class property margin-bottom: 6px to margin-bottom: 2px.

Do i need to add anything more for the fieldset  inline?

```
<fieldset id="counts" style="margin-bottom: 2px">
 <div runat="server" id="div1">
     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
  </div>
 <div id="div2" runat="server">
     <radC:RadComboBox ID="list" runat="server"/>
 </div>
</fieldset>

fieldset#counts div
{
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't override the `6px` property. They are targeting 2 different elements.

```
fieldset#counts div
```

targets the divs *inside* `<fieldset>`, and your inline style targets the `<fieldset>` element itself.

So the result is that `<fieldset>` has a 2px margin below it, and the two `<div>`s inside it both have a 6px margin.

To sort of diagram it out, your result is:

```
<fieldset id="counts" style="margin-bottom: 2px">
  <div runat="server" id="div1">
  </div>
  | <-- 6px margin
  <div id="div2" runat="server">
  </div>
  | <-- 6px margin
</fieldset>
| <-- 2px margin
```

---

**Additional answer based on comments:**

If you want the last div in the `fieldsets` element to have a `2px` margin instead of `6px` then you could do either of these in CSS:

```
#div2
{
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

-or-

```
fieldset#counts div:last-child
{
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Comment: @codingwithpike: </fieldset>
| <-- 6px margin. this i want to be 2px

Comment: I added additional info to my answer on how you can change the bottom-margin of the last div in the fieldset.

Comment: i have already added that margin-bottom property inline of the div2 but it didn't work for me

Comment: I have added the below line then it started working for me.still i don't know why the inline style is not overriding.THXs for your help.

 document.getElementById("<%=div2.ClientID%>").setAttribute("style", "margin-bottom: 2px");

Answer (score 0):

try to give it all in css id like :

```
<fieldset id="counts" >
 <div runat="server" id="div1">
     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
  </div>
 <div id="div2" runat="server">
     <radC:RadComboBox ID="list" runat="server"/>
 </div>
</fieldset>


#count {margin-bottom: 2px;}
#count div {margin-bottom: 6px;}
```

Comment: Added that part but didn't work me so I have added the below line then it started working for me.still i don't know why the inline style is not overriding.
 document.getElementById("<%=div2.ClientID%>").setAttribute("style", "margin-bottom: 2px");

thxs for ur time.

Comment: yes sure about that because u put on the div ... runat= "server"    this mean u will launch the div on the server and the css code is on the client side so its won't work ... but when u try to force the style in the c# code (server side) its work

Comment: every element in asp.net work on server side so its has an inherit id so if u want to reach it u should us the "name".ClientID

or u can set the id static in the tag "ClientID='Static'"

Comment: sorry because i miss the server tag on my answer